# Kial la tradukisto aldonis difinan artikolon (la) en ĉi tiun frazon?

Tags: grammar, article

> ...por eskapi de la akrega vento, rapide puŝis sin tra la vitrajn
> pordojn de **la Loĝejoj de la Venko**... (1984, tradukita de Donald Broadribb)

La frazo simple estas "Victory Mansions" (sen the) en la angla versio. Ĉu iuj propraj nomoj en esperanto prenas difinan artikolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laŭ [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) en la sekcio pri [la ĉe propraj nomoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html):

> Ĉe propraj nomoj la uzado de la estas bedaŭrinde iom malsimpla, kaj ne
> tute klare fiksita.
>
> [...]
>
> (En multaj lernolibroj oni trovas la
> trosimpligitan regulon: “antaŭ propraj nomoj oni ne uzas la”. Tiu
> simpligo ne estas prava.)

Ebla respondo al via demando aperas en [ordinaraj o-vortoj kiel propraj nomoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/difiniloj/la/propraj_nomoj.html#i-dlk):

> Antaŭ ordinaraj vortoj, kiuj fariĝis propraj nomoj, oni normale ja uzas la, ĉar la vortoj ne per si mem montras unikaĵojn:

Ekzemplo de PMEG:

```
Li kreis la Grandan Ursinon, Orionon, kaj Plejadojn.
```

Aliajn tiajn uzojn de `la` vi povas trovi en [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com), ekzempe per [tiu ĉi serĉo](https://tekstaro.com/?s=6546929e28e81).

```
Lasante la Novan Testamenton
ni intencis eldoni la Grandan Vortaron
mi ricevis la unuan numeron de la “Juna Esperantisto”
...
```